# How to know the operation of a notification message when I subscribe redis database?

Tags: redis, redis-py

I'm using redis-py. I subscribe to redis database and read notification like this:

```
>>> p.psubscribe("__keyspace@{}__:*".format(...))
>>> for message in p.listen():
...     # do something with the message
```

I want to get the operation of the message, like DELETE or ADD, how can I do this?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#publish--subscribe), when calling `listen()`, the `message` is returned as a dictionary:

> - type: One of the following: 'subscribe', 'unsubscribe', 'psubscribe', 'punsubscribe', 'message', 'pmessage'
> - channel: The channel [un]subscribed to or the channel a message was published to
> - pattern: The pattern that matched a published message's channel. Will be None in all cases except for 'pmessage' types.
> - data: The message data. With [un]subscribe messages, this value will be the number of channels and patterns the connection is currently subscribed to. With [p]message messages, this value will be the actual published message.

In the case of the '__keyspace*' pattern, the `data` key in the `message` dict holds the operation's name. Put differently:

```
>>> p.psubscribe("__keyspace@{}__:*")
>>> for message in p.listen():
...     print(message['data'])  # print the operation
```

Note: the call to `format(...)` appears to be not needed in your sample.